# tensorflow : tf.constant () wrong ouput

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Tensor is 'hello', the output will be preceded by a character b.
Tf.constant(b'hello') also has the same output. Same on Mac (python3.6) and window (python3.5) help......

Tensor is 'hello', the output will be preceded by a character b. Tf.constant(b'hello') also has the same output. Same on Mac (python3.6) and window (python3.5) help......

Here are scerenshots:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `b` before a string is not part of the string, but instead, denotes that it is stored as bytes. In Python 3.x, `bytes` and `string` objects are different (even though you can easily convert from one to the other).

So, `b'hello'` means that the string `hello` is being represented as bytes; this is the same as the string you inputted.

You can convert this value back to a string by using [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode), as `tf.constant().decode('ascii')`.